# Excel male and female filled chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I was creating a male and female chart, target to 100%, but the chart keeps breaking when both the filled values are 90%. Although I was doing it slightly different this video shows what I was trying to achieve, and even when I follow this video for 90% for both it still breaks the images
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVvzJtxEOgE[image];

Comment: I have tried the workflow from the video. I faced a similar issue that you described in the image when I did not properly copy paste the images on the right chart-bar. Please try re-doing it the same way as in the video.

Comment: @Gangula I did but the same result are you sure yours works at 90% for both?

Comment: I can confirm any woman who looks like that is 100% dead and the target has been achieved.

Comment: Following this video got me replicating it a 100%, not a problem here, Excel 2019.

Comment: @JvdV Try setting the values for both male and female at 100% does it work.

Comment: Yes it does, again, following the video exactly.

Comment: @JvdV I mean setting both the values for male and female to 100% at the same time. That still work?

Comment: If you're having trouble following the video, maybe try the written instructions? https://www.xelplus.com/creative-infographics-excel-male-female/

Comment: Yes it does that just fine :). Not sure what could be wrong on your end. You sure that `Filled` is the top data set?

Comment: @MichaelFrank I can follow the instructions I think it may be my Excel 365 that must have a bug

Comment: @JvdV Hmm that is strange and frustrating

Comment: @Naz, try recreating with your male and female as headers, so basically re-arranging your matrix. Might have something to do with how graphs process vertical against horizontal values. Worth a try.

Comment: @JvdV Finally figured it, the minimum axis value has to be 0, thank for your help.